# What does: "No wire-value is mapped to the enum foo position 16" error mean?

Tags: protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

> "No wire-value is mapped to the enum foo position 16"

What does this error message mean?

- i.) What is a wire-value?
- ii.) What is the position relative to?

In my particular situation I have:

> Additional information: No wire-value is mapped to the enum System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.0 at position 16

There is no representation in the enumeration for the integer 0, which I know. I think just knowing what the error report means will give me a better idea of how to solve this issue.

Comment: The "position 16" is *probably* talking about offset into the output buffer; for *serialization*, it probably helps me more than you; for *deserialization*, it may be more useful to the consumer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A "wire value" is the binary representation that it is going to use "on the wire", i.e. in the underlying stream. In this case, the fact that it has used `0` means that the value of the enum is 0, but that **it wasn't expecting a 0**, mostly likely because no enum member is defined that has the value if 0. If there were, it would have used the name, not `System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.0`. protobuf-net is trying to apply enum rules that enforce that the values make sense (and also optionally allow you to define maps between enum values and wire values, for some scenarios with external data)

There are various ways of avoiding this issue:

- don't try to serialize enum values that don't exist (or: add the missing values, if you control the enum)
- use `Nullable<SomeEnum>` (`SomeEnum?`) to serialize an enum that lacks a `None` value, when you want to represent that
- use a "shim" property that exposes the type as an `int` (or whatever the underlying type is) so that protobuf-net never tries to apply enum rules:

  ```
  public SomeEnum Foo {get;set;} // the actual member
  [ProtoMember(42)]
  private int FooSerialized { // only exists to help protobuf-net ignore the
      get { return (int)Foo; }// invalid values that the member might contain
      set { Foo = (SomeEnum)value; }
  }
  ```
- manually configure the model via `RuntimeTypeModel` and tell protobuf-net to ignore enum handling for this member, by setting `EnumPassthru` to `true`
- mark the enum declaration with `[Flags]`, which will make protobuf-net enable `EnumPassThru` automatically